# need help simplify, repetition code

Tags: r

```
function(q,b,Data1,Data2){  
x<-sum(
  ifelse(Data1[13+q,b]/Data1[12+q,b]>Data2[13+q,1]/Data2[12+q,1],1,0)+
  ifelse(Data1[13+q,b]/Data1[11+q,b]>Data2[13+q,1]/Data2[11+q,1],1,0)+
  ifelse(Data1[13+q,b]/Data1[10+q,b]>Data2[13+q,1]/Data2[10+q,1],1,0)+
  ifelse(Data1[13+q,b]/Data1[9+q,b]>Data2[13+q,1]/Data2[9+q,1],1,0)+
  ifelse(Data1[13+q,b]/Data1[8+q,b]>Data2[13+q,1]/Data2[8+q,1],1,0)+
  ifelse(Data1[13+q,b]/Data1[7+q,b]>Data2[13+q,1]/Data2[7+q,1],1,0)+
  ifelse(Data1[13+q,b]/Data1[6+q,b]>Data2[13+q,1]/Data2[6+q,1],1,0)+
  ifelse(Data1[13+q,b]/Data1[5+q,b]>Data2[13+q,1]/Data2[5+q,1],1,0)+
  ifelse(Data1[13+q,b]/Data1[4+q,b]>Data2[13+q,1]/Data2[4+q,1],1,0)+
  ifelse(Data1[13+q,b]/Data1[3+q,b]>Data2[13+q,1]/Data2[3+q,1],1,0)+
  ifelse(Data1[13+q,b]/Data1[2+q,b]>Data2[13+q,1]/Data2[2+q,1],1,0)+
  ifelse(Data1[13+q,b]/Data1[1+q,b]>Data2[13+q,1]/Data2[1+q,1],1,0)
)/12
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this? (no characters, only numbers in the data sets)

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you don't need `ifelse`. R automatically coerces to numerics if you do arithmetics with logical values. Then you can use `mean` instead of `sum(...)/12`. There is probably more, but my eyes glaze over if I try to understand what your code is doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two pieces of knowledge you can combine to improve your code:

**Firstly**, you can divide a single number by a vector and `R` will return a vector with elementwise divisions. For example:

```
5 / c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
# [1] 5.0000000 2.5000000 1.6666667 1.2500000 1.0000000 0.8333333
```

The numerator on both sides of the inequality are the same all the time, you can use the above. So instead of explicitly calling it for every inequality, you can just call it once.

**Secondly**, an expression with `TRUE` or `FALSE` will be coerced to `1` and `0` when you try to perform arithmetic operations (in your case division, or calculating a mean). Inequalities return `TRUE` or `FALSE` values. Explicitly telling `R` to convert them to `0` and `1` is wasted energy, because `R` will automatically do it in your last step.

**Putting this together** in a simplified function:

```
function(q, b, Data1, Data2){
  qseq <- (1:12) + q   # Replaces all "q+1", "q+2", ... , "q+12"

  dat1 <- Data1[qseq, b]  # Replaces all "Data1[q+1, b]", ... "Data1[q+12, b]"
  dat2 <- Data2[qseq, 1]  # Replaces all "Data2[q+1, 1]", ... "Data2[q+12, 1]"

  mean( Data1[13+q, b]/dat1 > Data2[13+q, 1]/dat2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

this simplify a bit:

```
function(q,b,Data1,Data2){  
    data1_num <- Data1[13+q,b]
    data2_num <- Data2[13+q,1]
    x <- 0 
    for (i in 1:12) {
        x <- x + ((data1_num/Data1[i+q,b]) > (data2_num /Data2[i+q,1]))
    } 
    x <- x /12
    #return(x)
}
```

But If you provide data example, and the output your expecting, i'm sure there is way to simplify it better